# Sorting lists in c++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, oop, integer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    string name, last_name;
    int age,id;

    Person(string nume, string prenume, int varsta,int id)
    {
        this->name = nume;
        this->last_name = prenume;
        this->age = varsta;
    }

    virtual void AfisarePersoana()
    {
        cout << "Nume: " << name;
        cout << "Prenume: " << last_name;
        cout << "Varsta: " << age;
    }
    int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
};

class Student : public Person
{
public: 
    string faculty, university;
    int year;

    Student(string nume, string prenume, int varsta, string facultate, string universitate, int an ,int id)
        :Person(nume,prenume,varsta,id)
    {
        this->faculty = facultate;
        this->university = universitate;
        this->year = an;
    }

    virtual void AfisarePersoana()
    {
        Person::AfisarePersoana();
        cout << "Universitate" << name;
        cout << "Facultate" << faculty;
        cout << "An" << year;
    }
};

class Employee : public Person
{
public:
    string specialization;
    int wage;

    Employee(string nume, string prenume, int varsta, string specializare, int salariu,int id)
        :Person(nume, prenume, varsta,id)
    {
        this->specialization = specializare;
        this->wage = salariu;
    }

    virtual void AfisarePersoana()
    {
        Person::AfisarePersoana();
        cout <<"Specializare: " << specialization;
        cout << "Salariu: " << wage;
    }



};

void add_student(list<Person*>& persons)
{
    string nume, prenume,facultate, universitate;
    int varsta,an;
    
    cout << "Dati numele persoanei: "; cin >> nume;
    cout << "Dati prenumele persoanei: "; cin >> prenume;
    cout << "Dati varsta: "; cin >> varsta;
    cout << "Dati facultatea: "; cin >> facultate;
    cout << "Dati universitatea: "; cin >> universitate;
    cout << "Dati anul: "; cin >> an;
     

    Person* st = new Student(nume, prenume, varsta,facultate,universitate, an,1);

    persons.push_back(st);

}

void add_angajat(list<Person*>& persons)
{
    string name, last_name, specialization;
    int age,wage;

    cout << "Dati numele persoanei: "; cin >> name;
    cout << "Dati prenumele persoanei: "; cin >> last_name;
    cout << "Dati varsta: "; cin >> age;
    cout << "Dati facultatea: "; cin >> specialization;
    cout << "Dati anul: "; cin >> wage;


    Person* st = new Employee(name, last_name, age, specialization, wage,2);

    persons.push_back(st);

}


void searching_person(list<Person*> persons,string nume)
{
    for (Person* st : persons)
    {
        if (st->name == nume)
        {
            st->AfisarePersoana();
        }
    }

}

void sorting_id(list<Person*>& persons)
{
    persons.sort([](Person* stanga, Person* dreapta)
        {
                        //I will get an error saying that the left of compare must have class/union/struct
            return stanga->id.compare(dreapta->id) < 0;
        });
}

int main() 
{
    list<Person*> persons;
    string nume;
    list<string> optiuni = {
        "1. Adaugare student",
        "2. Adaugare angajat",
        "2. Afisare studenti adaugati",
        "3. Cautare",
        "4. Stergere",
        "5. Modificare facultate",
        "6. Sortare studenti",
        "7. Exit"
    };

    do
    {
        cout << "Introdu optiunea: " << endl;
        for (string optiune : optiuni)
        {
            cout << optiune << endl;
        }
        int optiuni;
        cin >> optiuni;
        switch (optiuni)
        {
        case 1:
            add_student(persons);
            break;
        case 3:
            cin >> nume;
            searching_person(persons,nume);
            break;
        case 7:
            return false;
        default:
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to sort this list by id(id is automatically assigned if you are student(1),or employee(2)), i don't know how, thought of compare but i think it's only working with string , or if you can tell me how to sort by what type of class is ,i mean i want that students to be before employee in the list(that is why i want to sort by id )

Comment: The `id` member is an **`int`** variable. It doesn't have member functions. Why not simply `stanga->id < dreapta->id`?

Comment: If you use `<` instead of `compare` it will work with `int`, `string` and many other types.

Comment: it doesn't give that error anymore but, it doesn't sort either

Comment: On a different note, why are you using `std::list`? The "default" container should really be `std::vector`. What learning materials do you use? What classes are you taking? What does your text-books, tutorials or teachers say?

Comment: i am taking oop, and now i need to learn lists and how to sort , add and delete from it, this my first time with them

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my bad, i didnt use id in Person class constructor, (this->id= id), and didnt give any value so when i compared the two id were the same , some negative value -85000 or smt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, unless you're just learning about linked-lists, you should really default to `std::vector` as your go-to container.

Putting that aside, here's a working sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

struct Student {
  std::string name;
  int id;
};

int main() {
  std::list<Student> students{{"John", 4}, {"Alex", 2}, {"Jack", 3}};

  students.sort([](auto& s1, auto& s2) { return s1.id < s2.id; });

  for (auto& s : students) {
    std::cout << s.name << ' ' << s.id << '\n';
  }
}
```